# Alternative for Window function in SQLite version < 3.25.0?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, react-native, greatest-n-per-group

I want retrieve the last 10 rows for each chat_id match in a table.

This works perfect:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT a.*,
         row_number()
        OVER (PARTITION BY a.chat_id
    ORDER BY  a.timestamp DESC ) AS row
    FROM messages a ) AS foo
WHERE row <= 10
```

But when i put this code on my React Native app, it throws and error, and its because this its only supported in SQLite 3.25.0 and above.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Is there another way to do this? I'm trying to avoid multiple queries to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a correlated subquery to count how many records have the same `chat_id` and a greater `timestamp` than the current row, and use the result for filtering:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where (
    select count(*) 
    from messages m1 
    where m1.chat_id = m.chat_id and m1.timestamp > m.timestamp
) < 10
```

Comment: Thanks, It is what I needed.